# How to store child to child nodes and remove the immediate parent?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

We are parsing an xml and after serializing them ,it will be stored in database.

Our XML is look like below.

```
<SampleTypeService>
    <Name>sample1</Name>
    <URL>sample1</URL>
    <SampleTypeService_PK_ID>225d0266-e83a-44b8-88fc-700f6570d530</SampleTypeService_PK_ID>
    <SampleTypes>
        <SampleType_PK_ID>ef1d8c40-72ce-48d8-b252-9b521e96fa74</SampleType_PK_ID>
    </SampleTypes>
</SampleTypeService>

<SampleTypeService>
    <Name>sample2</Name>
    <URL>sample2</URL>
    <SampleTypeService_PK_ID>225reg66-e83a-44b8-88fc-700f6570d530</SampleTypeService_PK_ID>
    <SampleTypes>
        <SampleType_PK_ID>gh4d8c40-72ce-48d8-b252-9b521e96fa74</SampleType_PK_ID>
    </SampleTypes>
</SampleTypeService>
```

We need to store the value in `SampleType_PK_ID` in a string and then remove both

`SampleTypes` and `SampleType_PK_ID` node.

I am trying to delete it like below.

```
foreach (XmlNode SampleNode in SampleList)
{

    XmlNodeList ChildList = SampleNode.ChildNodes;
    for (int j = 0; j < ChildList.Count; j++)
    {

        if (ChildList[j].LocalName == "SampleType_PK_ID>")
        {
            strSampleTypePKID = ChildList[j].InnerText;
            if (strSampleTypePKID != null)
            {
                SampleNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(ChildList[j]); 
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    testString = SampleNode.OuterXml;
    Console.WriteLine("1):" + strSampleTypePKID);

   //Code to serialize and store in database is here.
}
```

But `strSampleTypePKID` is returning as empty string. What am I missing here. How to take the child to child node value and then delete it along with it's immediate parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the inner child node "SampleType_PK_ID" at the wrong level.
If you put a breakpoint at the line `strSampleTypePKID = ChildList[j].InnerText;`, you can see that it's never been executed.

Try the following instead:

```
foreach (XmlNode SampleNode in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
{
    strSampleTypePKID = string.Empty;
    var sampleTypesNode = SampleNode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(x => x.Name == "SampleTypes").FirstOrDefault();
    if (sampleTypesNode != null)
    {
        var pkNode = sampleTypesNode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(x => x.Name == "SampleType_PK_ID").FirstOrDefault();
        if (pkNode != null)
        {
            strSampleTypePKID = pkNode.InnerText;
            SampleNode.RemoveChild(sampleTypesNode);
        }
    }
    testString = SampleNode.OuterXml;
    Console.WriteLine("1):" + strSampleTypePKID);

   //Code to serialize and store in database is here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaner version of answer. Looks nice than having multiple loop.